# What's the altitude of the flat base of Cumulus clouds?

Tags: weather, atmospheric-science, meteorology

Is there a formula that describes the altitude of clouds with respect to the local temperature? I think of the *flat bases* of [Cumulus clouds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulus_cloud).

Thanks...

Comment: Wikipedia has the [approximate formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_base).
It depends on the [actual lapse rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate), which may differ from the standard "dry adiabatic" lapse rate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Ahrens R.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495555738)

> The bases of cumulus cloud can be estimated
>   quite easily when the surface air temperature
>   and dew point are known. If the air is not
>   too windy, we can assume that entrainment of
>   air will not change the characteristics of a rising
>   thermal. Since the rising air cools at the dry
>   adiabatic rate of about 10°C per 1000 m, and
>   the dew point drops at about 2°C per 1000 m,
>   the air temperature and dew point approach
>   each other at the rate of 8°C for every 1000 m
>   of rise. Rising surface air with an air temperature
>   and dew point spread of 8°C would produce
>   saturation and a cloud at an elevation of
>   1000 m. Put another way, a 1°C difference between
>   the surface air temperature and the dew
>   point produces a cloud base at 125 m. Therefore,
>   by finding the difference between surface
>   air temperature (T) and dew point ($T_{d}$), and
>   multiplying this value by 125, we can estimate
>   the base of the convective cloud forming overhead,
>   as
>   $H_{meter}=  125 (T-T_{d})$ .